# Duplicate rows in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 10, 21.0, 0), (3, 14, -23.0, 1)], ("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"))

df.show()

## +---+---+-----+---+
## | x1| x2|   x3| x4|
## +---+---+-----+---+
## |  1| 10| 23.0|  5|
## |  3| 14|-23.0|  0|
## +---+---+-----+---+
```

What would be an efficient way to "duplicate" rows and setting `x4=1` in those duplicates and have:

```py
## +---+---+-----+---+
## | x1| x2|   x3| x4|
## +---+---+-----+---+
## |  1| 10| 23.0|  5|
## |  1| 10| 23.0|  1|
## |  3| 14|-23.0|  0|
## |  3| 14|-23.0|  1|
## +---+---+-----+---+
```

In Apache PIG the analog would be simple: do a foreach and generate:

```py
FLATTEN(TOBAG(1, x4)) AS x4
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import required functions from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, explode, lit
```

and replace existing column:

```
df.withColumn("x4", explode(array(lit(1), df["x4"])))
```

Comment: +1 , this adds the same row in df, but what if I want to insert n rows, n could be another column value from df